# Less questions to answer?

Tags: discussion

Following this question: [Does it seem to anyone else like we're seeing less and less questions with accepted answers?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/does-it-seem-to-anyone-else-like-were-seeing-less-and-less-questions-with-accep)

- It seems the number of accepted answers is stable these days, and the ratio per question even increases.

However I've noticed the number of questions itself has decreased by more than 40% between February and April 2016 (and [May](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) confirms the trend):

[image]
(Weekly activity)

While there are now more upvotes per post, the number of posts itself decreased too, which is logical: less questions, less answers.

[image]
(Weekly activity)

Just wanted to share this, as we may want to all try and reboost the activity by some action.

---

I made [a query showing the last months](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/1451324#graph):

[image]

Comment: I did notice that trend too. I might just go and start asking some questions when I have the time to.

Comment: Looking at that graph, it looks like the Jan-Feb period was just anomalously high and the rate has returned to around what it was before that time. That's not to say that more (good) questions wouldn't be helpful, though.

Comment: @reirab: Jan-Feb were [as usual](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DGdjC.png) (if we exclude end of 2015 with more vacations around the world).

Comment: @mins Ah, yeah, looking at a longer time period, you're right.

Comment: Doesn't it look like the number of questions grew from November to February? Perhaps people spend more time on Stack Exchange during the Winter and less during Spring through Fall. Any data covering less than a year makes it hard to eliminate seasonal variation.

Comment: It seems that there is COVID effect in your update. After April 2021, there is a clear reduction of new visits and revisits. It's not as bad as the decline in actual air traffic, but there is a correlation.

Comment: Maximising the number of questions on the site equates to minimising the number of questions closed.

Answer (score 8):

It's seems like activity here kind of goes in fits and spurts.  I remember we had a lot of people posting and asking questions around the time MH370 disappeared, and each accident seems to bring in a few more people.  So we could just be seeing the tail end of something like that.

That being said, I'm noticing we are getting far more detailed questions these days, and I think that's a good thing.  There are only so many basic aviation question, but there are endless technical questions about particular aircraft and airports, etc.  So as the site pulls in more and more experts, I think we'll see, year over year, a positive trend in questions asked.

Comment: Speaking of accidents, we might just have more coming in because of one.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann We may see an uptick, that's for sure.  Especially after they get ahold of the black box and we have some real data...

Comment: Here is the first one. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27646/why-would-a-pilot-do-this-egypt-plane